# Dropdown Not Populating with Dynamic Data in React Component

Tags: javascript, load, dropdown

### Question:

I am working on a React project where I need to populate a dropdown with data based on the selected diagnosis from a list. Despite the useEffect hook correctly processing the data for the dropdown, the dropdown remains empty and does not display the expected values.

### Code Snippet:

I have a useEffect hook that processes lab data and sets up data for a dropdown component. The relevant part of the code looks like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const findDiagnosisDetailsById = (icdId) => {
    // Function to find diagnosis details
  };

  // Mapping and processing data
  let labsDataForEdit = labDataForUpdate?.map((lab) => {
    const diagnosisDetails = findDiagnosisDetailsById(lab?.icdId);
    return {
      // object structure
      selectedDiagnosis: diagnosisDetails ? [{ id: diagnosisDetails?.id, label: diagnosisDetails?.label }] : [],
    };
  });

  setComponents([...labsDataForEdit, ...labsSetDataForEdit]);
}, [labDataForUpdate, labSetDataForUpdate, diseaseDiagnosisDropdownData]);
```

For the dropdown component, I am using it like this:

```
<Dropdown
  value={rowData.selectedDiagnosis}
  options={diseaseDiagnosisDropdownData}
  optionLabel="label"
  onChange={(e) => handleDiagnosisChange(rowData.id, e.value)}
  placeholder="Select a diagnosis"
/>
```

### What I've tried:

1. Verified that diseaseDiagnosisDropdownData contains the correct data structure and is correctly passed to the Dropdown component.
2. Checked that rowData.selectedDiagnosis matches an item's id from diseaseDiagnosisDropdownData.
3. Added console logs to ensure that data is present and correctly formatted before it's used by the dropdown.

### Problem:

The dropdown does not show any of the expected diagnosis options, despite the console.log confirming that combinedDataForEdit contains the correct data structure and values.

### Question:

How can I ensure that the dropdown is populated with the data as expected? Is there an issue with how I'm setting the value or options for the Dropdown component?

Comment: can you maybe share a code sandbox for the issue

Comment: It's not clear how those two code examples work together.